# Can I simulate an input button disabled state in Firefox?

Tags: jquery, css

The following will not show the toolbar tip in Firefox when the button is disabled. It's a known bug (since 2008)

```
<button disabled="disabled" class="sel" title="Task: 22">@i</button>
```

Is there another way I could simulate "disabled" state using CSS / jQuery?

Comment: when you want the button to be disabled you could simply set a variable to false. Then if they click the button you could check the variable and just return false if it should be disabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could assign a class "disabled"

```
$('#ele').addClass('disabled');
```

Then you could bind a click event that checks if the "disabled" is in the cass list, if so, return false to stop the event:

```
$('#ele').bind('click', function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('disabled'))
    {
         return false;
    }
});
```

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Of course, that will not make your button appear disabled to the user.

Comment: I need some visual clue for the user also.

Comment: Change the colour of the text of the button using CSS?

Comment: button.disabled{ color:#ccc; }

Comment: Yes, you'll have to take care of presenting a visual clue yourself.